# package maneger broken. unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I tried to fix one problem and created another...

My update manager broke...

> The package system is broken
>
> Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them,
>   since they are a common source of problems. Furthermore run the
>   following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

I run `apt-get install -f` and I get:

```
missx@missx:~$ apt-get install -f
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I tried reinstalling software center i get this

```
missx@missx:~$ sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-center
[sudo] password for missx: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 network-manager-dbg : Depends: network-manager (= 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3) but 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed or
                                libnm-util2 (= 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3) but 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed or
                                libnm-glib4 (= 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3) but 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed or
                                libnm-glib-vpn1 (= 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3) but 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The network maneger is the piece of crap I installed yesterday to fix my wi-fi issue...

Don't have synaptic installed (that would be too easy, right..?)

`sudo apt-get -f install`

```
missx@missx:~$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.2.0-38 libsub-name-perl libparse-debianchangelog-perl
  libnspr4-0d:i386 libsigc++-2.0-0c2a:i386 libcwidget3
  libboost-iostreams1.46.1 libgconf2-4:i386 libapt-pkg4.12:i386
  libio-string-perl linux-headers-3.2.0-38-generic libept1.4.12
  libclass-accessor-perl libnss3-1d:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  network-manager-dbg
The following packages will be upgraded:
  network-manager-dbg
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,463 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,192 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of network-manager-dbg:
 network-manager-dbg depends on network-manager (= 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3) | libnm-util2 (= 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3) | libnm-glib4 (= 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3) | libnm-glib-vpn1 (= 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3); however:
  Version of network-manager on system is 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.2.
  Version of libnm-util2 on system is 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.2.
  Version of libnm-glib4 on system is 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.2.
  Version of libnm-glib-vpn1 on system is 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.2.
dpkg: error processing network-manager-dbg (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                      Errors were encountered while processing:
```

network-manager-dbg
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Comment: you miss typed the command.  You missed an 'l' out the command is `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Just do `sudo apt-get remove network-manager-dbg` and you will get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to reinstall software center.

The "apt-get install" command needs "sudo" in front of it.

As you can see from the error message
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: **Permission denied**) E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), **are you root?**

I don't know what your wireless issue was, but I don't see why installing network manager would have fixed it (considering network manager is installed by default and from the messages you posted, I'm guessing you just upgraded it)

Comment: missx@missx:~$ sudo apt-get -f instal
[sudo] password for missx: 
E: Invalid operation instal

Comment: @Shellby You typo'd install. When you have an error please at least read it and make an attempt to comprehend what it is saying.